# BSONSerializer for generic JsArray

Tags: scala, reactivemongo

I need to make a BSONSerializer for my case class Filter that looks the following way.

```
case class Filter(name: String,
              `type`: LogicType,
              value: JsArray,
              operator: OperatorType)
```

Within my serializer class I already have the following guys:

```
    implicit val LogicTypeHandler: BSONHandler[LogicType] = EnumHandler.handler(LogicType)
    implicit val OperatorTypeHandler: BSONHandler[OperatorType] = EnumHandler.handler(OperatorType)
>>> Missing BSON serializer for JsArray
    implicit val FilterHandler: BSONDocumentHandler[Filter] = Macros.handler[Filter]
```

The issue is that I need to save "value" as JsArray and only during later runtime usage I will know what it will be exactly.
In my case I'm expecting it to be wether array of Strings or Ints.
The question here is how to implement BSONSerializer for this JsArray. I'm getting error:

```
Implicit not found for 'Filter.value': reactivemongo.api.bson.BSONReader[play.api.libs.json.JsArray]
```

Additional info:

```
"org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "1.0.0-play28"
"com.typesafe.play" % "sbt-plugin" % "2.8.5"
```

Please advise.

Comment: Check the required imports are properly used as indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/json/overview.html). There are many discussions about that in the [MailingList](https://groups.google.com/g/reactivemongo). Also using a `JsValue` doesn't seem a good design.

Comment: @cchantep  Next BSONHandler is getting errors during testing with "scala.util.Success cannot be cast to play.api.libs.json.JsArray"
`code`
  implicit val JsArrayHandler: BSONHandler[JsArray] = new BSONHandler[JsArray] {
    import reactivemongo.play.json.compat._
    override def readTry(bson: BSONValue): Try[JsArray] = Success(bson) << automatically compiles to Success[BSONValue] instead of desired Try[JsArray] 
//    override def readTry(bson: BSONValue): Try[JsArray] = Try(Success(bson).asInstanceOf[JsArray])
    override def writeTry(t: JsArray): Try[BSONValue] = Success(t)
  }

Comment: There is no way this code could work, moreover with appropriate import according indicated doc it's useless.

Comment: i already have "org.reactivemongo" %% "play2-reactivemongo" % "1.0.0-play28" and it told in the documentation: "If the dependency for the Play plugin (with the right version) is present, it already provides the JSON support and this JSON serialization pack must not be added as a separate dependency." I'm assuming that my usage is correct .. or I'm missing something?  @cchantep many thanks for your guidelines

Comment: Build dependency is different from import

Comment: Solution is to add to BSONSerializer the following imports:
import reactivemongo.play.json.compat._
// Override conversions with lax syntax
import lax._
// Conversions from JSON to BSON
import json2bson._
while JSONSerializer needs to include these ones:
import reactivemongo.play.json.compat._
// Conversions from BSON to JSON extended syntax
import bson2json._
// Override conversions with lax syntax
import lax._

Comment: As indicated in the [documentation](http://reactivemongo.org/releases/1.0/documentation/json/overview.html) ...